# Select a part from the daterange column type

Tags: postgresql, date-range

Maybe there is a function?

`SELECT min('[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)'::daterange);` Should return: '2010-01-01'

`SELECT max('[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)'::daterange);` Should return: '2010-01-31'

Comment: Just for clarity, I'd call those functions "minimum" and "maximum" instead of "part_one" and "part_two"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could use `upper_inc`, `upper`, `lower_inc`, `lower` functions to write such a function:

```
WITH dr AS (
  SELECT '[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)'::daterange r
), t AS (
  SELECT r, lower_inc(r) li, upper_inc(r) ui, lower(r) l, upper(r) u FROM dr
)
SELECT CASE WHEN li THEN l ELSE l + INTERVAL '1 DAY' END AS "range_minimum"
     , CASE WHEN ui THEN u ELSE u - INTERVAL '1 DAY' END AS "range_maximum"
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the starting point:

```
SELECT lower('[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)'::daterange);  
01/01/2010
```

since it is inclusive

For upper:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
      upper_inc('[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)'::daterange) = 'f' 
   THEN 
       upper('[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)'::daterange) - interval '1 day' 
   ELSE 
       upper('[2010-01-01, 2010-02-01)'::daterange) END AS dt;  

01/31/2010 00:00:00
```